# HTACCESS redirect traffic to a specific page depending on referrer to different landing pages

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I've been trying to redirect incoming traffic to a specific url depending on the referrer but so far with no luck.

Example:

I have a specific page like domain.com/page and I want to redirect all incoming traffic to that page to different landing pages depending on the referrer.

So if the traffic to this page comes from domain.com/page1 the visitor should be redirected to domain.com/landingpage1

If the traffic comes from domain.com/page2 the user shoud be redirected to domain.com/landingpage2 and so on.

This is what I tried so far...

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*domain.com/page.*$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} .*domain.com/page1.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/landingpage1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*domain.com/page.*$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} .*domain.com/page2.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/landingpage2

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*domain.com/page.*$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} .*domain.com/page3.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/landingpage3
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: The domain is not part of the request URI. (And why are you checking the domain anyway, do you have other domains pointing to the same webspace?)

Comment: I didn't know that. No I don't have other domains pointing to the same webspace.

Comment: Well then what are those conditions supposed to achieve?

Comment: as you can see I have no idea of what I'm doing so do you have a working solution? I thought I have to check for the url since I only want to redirect traffic to this specific url.

Comment: Use the RewriteRule pattern to check for that.

Comment: sorry, but I don't know how to do that.